# Navigation resets when switching fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have the following navigation xml on a `BottomNavigationView`, however when the user navigates inside the 1st fragment and then navigates to another fragment using the `BottomNavigationView` and then comes back to the initial fragment, it resets all the way to the default 1st fragment the navigation to a deeper fragment does not persist, i assume this is because the fragment gets recreated and from what i've looked at on other questions is that there is a way to save the data to re-set any text values on text fields or similar stuff, however i haven't seen if theres a way to avoid the fragment from being destroyed and re-created in order to make the navigation and whatever changes the user had previously made to the view persist.

Is there a way to do that, or should i use a `savedInstance` in such a way that it re-navigates to the previously navigated fragment?

[image: it no work]

Comment: What version of Navigation are you using? Are you already [saving your state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) across configuration changes and process death and recreation?

Comment: @ianhanniballake
i'm implenting this version of navigation 'navigation-fragment:2.3.5' as for saving state, not yet i wanted to ask first because i'm not aware if this will fix my issue or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of [Navigation 2.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation#version_240_2) is support for [multiple back stacks](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/multiple-back-stacks-b714d974f134) - i.e., the ability for each tab of a bottom navigation bar to save its state, restoring that state when you reselect that tab.

As per that blog post:

> If you’re using `NavigationUI`, our set of opinionated helpers for connecting your NavController to Material view components, you’ll find that multiple back stacks is enabled by default for menu items, `BottomNavigationView` (and now `NavigationRailView`!), and `NavigationView`. This means that the common combination of using `navigation-fragment` and `navigation-ui` will just work.

This means that if you are using the `setupWithNavController` methods, then upgrading to Navigation 2.4 will give you support for multiple back stacks immediately. You can verify that by going to your order fragment (thus building a back stack on that first tab), going to a different tab, then tap on the first tab again to reselect it.

Of course, it is your fragments *state*, not the instances themselves that are saved and restored. This means that each individual fragment must still [save its state](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/saving-state) properly.

Comment: I see, i'll check that out right now and yes this is what i need, saving states is not something i require for the time being!

Comment: Yup, instantly worked after updating to the 2.4.0-beta01 version of navigation, no extra setup required.

Comment: How to NOT save state with new navigation 2.4.0 ?